# How can I convert a string into a TColor Value?

Tags: delphi

I am creating a Delphi form and want to assign background color to it on run time. This code:

```
Form1.Color := clSkyBlue;
```

works well. My problem is that I have stored the color name in a table as a string. So, when I fetch the color name from the table and assign it to `Form1.Color`, the above statement becomes:

```
var
  ColorName: string;
....
Form1.Color := ColorName;
```

and this results in a compile time error.

How can I convert a string to a `TColor` value?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the following conversion functions (both works with color constants):

- the [`StringToColor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Graphics.StringToColor) function use to translate a string representation of a color to [`TColor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Graphics.TColor) value
- the [`ColorToString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Graphics.ColorToString) function use when you need to translate [`TColor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Graphics.TColor) value to a string representation

In your case you need to use the [`StringToColor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Graphics.StringToColor) function:

```
Form1.Color := StringToColor('clSkyBlue');
```

Comment: Ohh wow!!! thanks tlama. I was not knowing this keyword. Also, I googled 'how to convert tstring into tcolor in delphi xe2', but I did not found any thing helpful. Thanks again!!

Comment: @user1556433 There is no `TString`. You mean string.

Comment: You didn't find anything because there is no built-in `TString` type in Delphi. It's just `string`.

Comment: @user1556433 you could find this simply tracing how your form is loading from DFM

Comment: @Arioch'The That uses `IdentToColor` if memory serves. It's also not the easiest thing to do, step through .dfm loading. Seriously, you need a fair bit of knowledge to get the debugger to stop at the call to `IdentToColor`.

Answer (score 0):

You can find all of these routines in **GraphUtil.pas**.

{ Converts a TColor to a Web color constant like #FFFFFF }

```
function ColorToWebColorStr(Color: TColor): string;
```

{ Converts a TColor to a Web color name, returns a Web color value if the color is not a match. }

```
function ColorToWebColorName(Color: TColor): string;
function WebColorToRGB(WebColor: Integer): Integer;
function RGBToWebColorStr(RGB: Integer): string;
function RGBToWebColorName(RGB: Integer): string;
```

{ Converts a Web color name to its TColor equivalent, returns clNone if no match }

```
function WebColorNameToColor(WebColorName: string): TColor;
```

{ Converts a web style color string (#FFFFFF or FFFFFF) to a TColor }

```
function WebColorStrToColor(WebColor: string): TColor;
```

*answer by Hans*